# Best practices for REST-API models

Tags: rest, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model, mvp

I am working on a REST-API and have run into an architectural problem.

The model 'Book' represents a single book with properties and CRUD-based functions. It loads itself from a database via a read function.

However, what if I want to get all books in the database? The current book model does not cover this use case.

I have tried several approaches:

1.) A second model called 'Books'. It has a read function which returns a list of book objects.

2.) The model 'Book' itself has a readAll function which loads all books.

3.) The model 'Book' is non-functional, it only has properties. Instead a 'BookStorage' class loads the data and fills one/multiple models.

I am not satisfied with any of these approaches. Is there a best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with any of these?  Number 1 seems like a good option.

Comment: You title the question about REST API, which usually relates to the service interface (typically HTTP+JSON or XML). But you also ask about classes and data access, which is behind the HTTP service interface (in your native programming language). So i think it will help to clarify if your question is the service/HTTP interface or behind the service code.

Comment: @DavinTryon i think it's not really intuitive, especially if new people join the project. also hard to read if u have most of the times singular and plural model (Book.php, Books.php, Author.php, Authors.php, ...)

Comment: But they do *mean* two different things.  One means give me a list of all books and one is give me a single book.  And you don't have to *always* expose a plural interface (only if it makes sense to the client).

Comment: [REST API Architecture – Best Practices](http://dasunhegoda.com/rest-api-architecture-best-practices/1049/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.) A second model called 'Books'. It has a read function which returns a list of book objects.

This is okay, but users and future developers on the project may be unclear on the fact that you have both Book and Books. So be sure to document the API, and comment the code. Also, you do need to consider input filters to limit down the results, or at least a method to page results. Google once estimated there were 130 million books, so you want to get all of them at once?

e.g. SERVER/Books/?skipRecords=0&limit=100

> 2.) The model 'Book' itself has a readAll function which loads all books.

This is not ideal as it violates the single responsibility principal. Mostly it just doesn't make a lot of sense in an OO situation to have a single book entity be able to list all of it's sibling entities.

e.g. SERVER/TheHobbit/readAll.... yuck.

> 3.) The model 'Book' is non-functional, it only has properties. Instead a 'BookStorage' class loads the data and fills one/multiple
>   models.
>   If you can expose these functional extension via the API, then that is an fine solution as well. It all comes down to documentation.

Maybe it ends up looking like this

e.g.

SERVER/BookStorage/GetAllBooks?skipRecords=0&limit=100

SERVER/BookStorage/GetBook?title=TheHobbit

Comment: do you have any other ideas? or are solution 1 and 3 the "only options".

Answer (score 0):

> 3.) The model 'Book' is non-functional, it only has properties. Instead a 'BookStorage' class loads the data and fills one/multiple models.

This approach is similar to the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) and is very common. The BookStorage would be a BookRepository with an interface like:

```
public interface IBookRepository
{
    Book GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<Book> GetAll();
    // Other methods for creating, updating and deleting books.
}
```

In your controller you would then have:

```
public class BooksController: ApiController
{
    private readonly IBookRepository _bookRepository;

    public BooksController(IBookRepository bookRepository)
    {
        _bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    [Route("api/books/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var book = _bookRepository.GetById(id);

        // ...
    }

    [Route("api/books")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var books = _bookRepository.GetAll();

        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want paging, you would add a filter like `Get(int page = 0)` and then depending on your page size, use something like `bookRepository.GetAll().Skip(PAGE_SIZE * page).Take(PAGE_SIZE)`.

A model should not load itself as it would violate the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 0):

A great resource when designing RESTful webservices is Martin Fowler's article [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

To summarise for your `book` case:

- use `POST /book` to create a book
- use `PUT /book` to update a book
- use `GET /book?author=Shakespeare&year=1602&someOtherParam=someValue` to find books
- use `GET /book/:id` to retrieve the details of a particular book
- use `DELETE /book/:id` to delete a certain book

Also you might want to follow the [HATEOAS](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS) principles, so you'll need to include all relevant links for a book into a `links` property, so that clients of your API will not need to build their own link when they'll want to add/edit/find/delete a book.

Although simple at first sight, designing a good RESTful webservice is not that easy, however HATEOAS helps because url schema changes on the server side don't affect clients as they don't hardcode the URL's needed for the `CRUD` operations. All you need to do is provide a starting point, e.g. a base url where all contents can be discovered, and clients can start from there navigating through your webservice.

Comment: yeah... but the question is how do you handle
    `use GET /book?author=Shakespeare&year=1602&someOtherParam=someValue to find books`
request in your models @Cristik

Comment: The `search` request can be mapped to a static method `find(query)`, where `query` corresponds to a dictionary/map of key+values. This is similar to option #2 from your question

Answer (score 0):

Read the [CRUD Operations](http://dasunhegoda.com/rest-api-architecture-best-practices/1049/) section here. You will find REST best practices to be followed when designing a REST API